# Working with wchar in C

Tags: c, gcc, header

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
  wchar_t *foo = L"ðħ";
  wprintf(L"[%ls]\n", foo);      return 0;
}
```

And when I compile it, it gives me the `implicit declaration of function ‘wprintf’` warning. I know that I should link the wchar library during compilation, but how do I do that?

Comment: I think Matt wants to know what version of GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried invoking the compiler with -std=c99 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any warnings when I compile your program.  I'm using gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1) on OS X.